# Eclipse indigo no longer starts after update

Tags: eclipse

I have updated my eclipse indigo in my ubuntu 11.10. After updating, when i am trying to open it shows an error message

```
An error has occured. See the log file
/home/rakhi/eclipse/configuration/139201239824.log
```

The log file shows the following

```
!SESSION 2014-02-10 10:48:11.555 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.495
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (329).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 42 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 42 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui_1.0.100.v20111213-1754.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.5.101.v20120110-1739.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui_3.3.300.v20110305-1450.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.6.1.v20111006_r372.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.7.1,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.junit_3.7.0.v20110928-1453.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui_1.0.301.v20110803_r371.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.567
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.7.1,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.568
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.pde.ui_3.6.100.v20120103_r372.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.568
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.568
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.pde.ua.ui_1.0.100.v20110516.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ua.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.568
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.4.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.575
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.575
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui_3.3.300.v20110305-1450 [108] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.575
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui_1.0.301.v20110803_r371 [134] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.7.1,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.pde.ua.ui_1.0.100.v20110516 [144] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ua.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ua.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.5.101.v20120110-1739 [236] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.junit_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.6.1.v20111006_r372 [285] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.7.1,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.junit_3.7.0.v20110928-1453 [288] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui_1.0.100.v20111213-1754 [302] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.576
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui_3.6.100.v20120103_r372 [305] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.577
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.577
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.577
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ant.ui_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ui 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.577
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.junit_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.577
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates_3.4.400.v20110928-1516 [306] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates 2 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.577
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui_[3.3.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-02-10 10:48:12.578
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.ui.ide.application" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (329).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 42 more
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to update eclipse. There are lots of issues laying around regarding this. I myself faced a similar issue when I tried to series-update my `indigo` to `juno`.

The best advice that I can give you is that to download a fresh copy of the latest eclipse version , install the plugins that you require and don't attempt to update it.

It seems that updating eclipse is not a walk in the park

Comment: @DownVoter I don't mind criticism but can you atleast comment on it ?

Comment: Upvoted, I made the same experiences when updating Eclipse. Sad enough.